# What html tags should be removed when posting a form?

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I'm just creating a form where the user can write in html and I would like to know what html tags should I remove for security reasons. This form is sent to a PHP file, so I was thinking to remove the non desired tags by using **strip_tags**.

So far, the only ideas I have is to remove script and div (to avoid breaking layout) tags.

What else should I parse to avoid security and layout problems ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer may depend on the level of "safe" you want to achieve.

If you want to be *really* safe, I'm afraid you have to remove ALL html tags. As the documentation of `strip_tags` says it, any tags you allow can be abused by the `style` and `onmouseover` attributes.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

If you want to allow formatting, I recommend using a markdown editor instead. You will find good ideas in this other question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357022/what-is-a-good-client-side-markdown-editor

Answer (score 3):

These HTML cause *Code Injection* as explained in [this ariticle](http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html):

**`<SCRIPT>`**: Adds a script that is to be used in the document.

**`<OBJECT>`**: Places an object (such as an applet, media file, etc.) on a document. The tag often contains information for retrieving ActiveX controls that IE uses to display the object.

**`<APPLET>`**: Used to place a Java applet on a document. It is depreciated in the HTML 4.0 specification in favour of  tag.

**`<EMBED>`**:  Embeds an object into the document. Embedded objects are most often multimedia files that require special plug-ins to display. Specific media types and their respective plug-ins may have additional proprietary attributes for controlling the playback of the file. The closing tag is not always required, but is recommended. The tag was dropped by the HTML 4.0 specification in favour of the  tag.

**`<FORM>`**:   Indicates the beginning and end of a form.

And also take a look at the `htmlentities()` function of php. This function is identical to `htmlspecialchars()` in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities. See more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 1):

Semantics really I suppose, but the immediate answer should be "all of them".

Your question should be framed more like "which tags do I allow in?".

The difference being: you nuke everything, except the ones you want to allow (from the "white list") rather than allowing everything except those on the "black list".

So, spin your question round and you will be on the right track.

Then go and read about the PHP class [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

ADDED: If you want to know the true extent of what you are tring to protect yourself, then read your way carefully through this definition from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

If your server has SSI (Server Side Includes) enabled, you might also want to disallow SSI includes.

SSI look something like `<!--# something here -->`.

For example, `<!--#exec cmd="del *.*"-->` will delete everything from your server if you are displaying the input from the user on some page.

Hope this was of some help.